# Simulate long press on home button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-homebutton

If I want to simulate press on home button I do this

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

But how can I simulate long press?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override the home button. Android doesn't allow it because of security reasons. But to handle de long press on a button, you can use `onKeyLongPress`

Comment: I do not want to override it !, I just want to simulate press of it programmatic-ally (e.g fore some kind of intent), I do not know if this is possible, that is why I asked :)

Comment: I'm sorry I guess I misunderstood it. I really don't know what you want. Correct me if I'm wrong: you want to do the same action that the home button is long pressed but without pressing any button? I mean,do you want to show the list of recent activities?

Comment: Yes, I want to simulate long pressing. I want to see the recent activities with out actually pressing on the home button

Comment: maybe, this link helps http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e9923d3a1dc760bf# or at least gives you the hint you need